# Plotly_Express - 'method' object is not subscriptable - Normal Excel File

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

hope that this issue is not redundant. I'm trying to visualize data in a similar fashion to the Gapminder example. The test with px.data.gapminder() runs splendid. However, when I try to transfer the principle on similarly shaped Excel file of own data, the titled error appears. Here the code:

```
import plotly_express as px
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

Heisei = pd.read_excel("日本ダム/NihonGapmindFormTest.xlsx")
print(Heisei)

#display of Japanese characters
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Kozuka Mincho Pr6N']
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Kozuka Mincho Pr6N']

px.scatter(Heisei, x="Inauguration Year", y="Percent to Dead Volume", animation_frame="Year", animation_group="Dam Name",
           size="Percent to Whole Volume", color="Dam Name", hover_name="Dam Name", 
           #log_y = True, 
           size_max=45, range_x=[1910,2020], range_y=[-100,1000])
```

The table includes no NaNs. Dash.ly seems not to be installed. At least it couldn't be pip uninstalled, as it wasn't found.

This is the complete error warning.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2fdd1e6f0c53> in <module>()
      2            size="Percent to Whole Volume", color="Dam Name", hover_name="Dam Name",
      3            #log_y = True,
----> 4            size_max=45, range_x=[1910,2020], range_y=[-100,1000])

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\plotly_express\_chart_types.py in scatter(data_frame, x, y, color, symbol, size, hover_name, hover_data, text, facet_row, facet_col, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, color_continuous_midpoint, symbol_sequence, symbol_map, opacity, size_max, marginal_x, marginal_y, trendline, trendline_color_override, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, render_mode, title, template, width, height)
     59     In a scatter plot, each row of `data_frame` is represented by a symbol mark in 2D space.
     60     """
---> 61     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
     62 
     63 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\plotly_express\_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
    653 def make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch={}, layout_patch={}):
    654     trace_specs, grouped_mappings, sizeref, color_range = infer_config(
--> 655         args, constructor, trace_patch
    656     )
    657     grouper = [x.grouper or one_group for x in grouped_mappings] or [one_group]

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\plotly_express\_core.py in infer_config(args, constructor, trace_patch)
    589     sizeref = 0
    590     if "size" in args and args["size"]:
--> 591         sizeref = args["data_frame"][args["size"]].max() / (
    592             args["size_max"] * args["size_max"]
    593         )

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

As said, I hope this is not redundant. If so, please link me to the respective issue.

Lots of thanks in advance,
Tobias